# How to find the dynamic added classNames using angular

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, jqlite

In my view I have couple of divs whose ids are :

```
<div ng-src="{{board[0].url)}}" autosize="off" id="{{board[0].name}}"></div>
  <div ng-src="{{{board[1].url)}}"autosize="off" id="{{board[1].name}}"></div>
```

I need to fetch those divs based on their ids and apply styling to it. How can I achieve that? Is there something like this :

```
angular.forEach($scope.boards, function(board){
    $document.find('#board.name').css({'width': board.position.width, 'height' : board.position.height})
}
```

Comment: Maybe a custom attribute to consolidate the selection for styling is better than relying on dynamic values? You could add `data-id="board"` for example to each "board" div that shares the same style and base your selector on that.

Comment: All the divs have different styles. Thats why they should have different ids

Comment: Either way, driving styles from dynamic values seems unreliable and brittle. If you can drive the styles by static values or position within a child/parent relationship that might be better. But if you can make your script use the same variables that drive your dynamic identifiers than it should be OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to use jquery and [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) directive could do the same thing for you

```
<div ng-src="{{board[0].url)}}" ng-style="{width:board[0].position.width,height:board[0].position.height}" autosize="off" id="{{board[0].name}}"></div>
<div ng-src="{{{board[1].url)}}" ng-style="{width:board[1].position.width,height:board[1].position.height}" autosize="off" id="{{board[1].name}}"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could

```
$document.find('#' + board.name).css({'width': board.position.width, 'height' : board.position.height})
```

But then again, this code needs to be executed after angular finishes rendering the HTML interpolation, which is difficult to determine.

A better approach would be to use the ng-style which was meant for situations like this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

So:

```
<div ng-src="{{board[0].url)}}" ng-style="{width: board[0].position.width, height: board[0].position.height}" autosize="off" id="{{board[0].name}}"></div>
```

...